# Concurrent programming: synchronization of three theads using semaphores

Tags: concurrency, synchronization, semaphore

We have three processes, which run concurrently and consist of the following statements:

| P | Q | R |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 p2 p3 | q1 q2 q3 | r1 r2 r3 |

> Synchronize P, Q and R, fullfilling all of the conditions
> simulatenously:
>
> - p1 must execute before q2
> - q1 must execute before r2
> - r1 must execute before p2
> - r3 must execute after p2 and q2

First I tried this:

```
pCompleted = Semaphore(0)
qCompleted = Semaphore(0)
rCompleted = Semaphore(0)
bothCompleted = Semaphore(0)
```

| P: | Q: | R: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 pCompleted.signal() rCompleted.wait() p2 bothCompleted.signal() p3 | q1 qCompleted.signal() pCompleted.wait() q2 bothCompleted.signal() q3 | r1 rCompleted.signal() qCompleted.wait() r2 bothCompleted.wait() bothCompleted.wait() r3 |

It is needless to say this is extremely ineffective, maybe even wrong.
I think I can drop at least one semaphore without causing a deadlock:

| P: | Q: | R: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 pCompleted.signal() rCompleted.wait() p2 pCompleted.signal() p3 | q1 qCompleted.signal() pCompleted.wait() q2 qCompleted.signal() q3 | r1 rCompleted.signal() qCompleted.wait() r2 pCompleted.wait() qCompleted.wait() r3 |

Still, I highly doubt this is a good solution. 
Could somebody suggest an optimal solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be achieved quite easily with four CountDownLatches. For example,

```
CountDownLatch p1q2 = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

controls the synchronization between threads P and Q for the first bullet. Q waits on p1q2 before entering q2, and P countdowns p1q2 after exiting p1. And so on.

Note that the r3p2q2 would have to wait for two countdowns.

(And, obviously, you also need a thread D, with statements d1 and d2, where d2 must execute after r2 ;) )